# Help identify IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components, surface-mount, light

This is an LED light from AI, PRIME 16HD model.

I have identified the IC that seems to be burned; it looks like it's some kind of voltage regulator. I think the markings are:  BN0D  18.

Maybe someone can identify it.  I googled for it and obviously couldn't find anything. I sent a question to AI support, but I'm still waiting for an unlikely positive answer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are those marks on the board-to-board PCB? I can't tell from the picture but it looks damaged too.

Comment: no. it looks ok.  I have a led burned as well.  but right now there is no power.  so first I need to fix this part. if only will be able to find out what it is

Comment: it should be a regulator to drop from 24v to 5v  I assume.  thinking that the controller circuit  is working with 5v.

Comment: The multiple cuts in the brown wire are rather worrying.

Comment: Actually looks like a burn mark at R1 below the brown wire too. There's a lot of fishy damage overall, this might be beyond repair.

Comment: So... possible scenario: someone completely botched the peeling of the wires during assembly. The exposed wire then at some point shorts against R1, possibly killing a trace there, as well as the switch regulator U11 and likely the diode D9 too. At the same time, traces on the same supply net also provided to the board-to-board PCB gets fried. The victim is found dead and all rescue attempts failed to save them.`</sherlock>`

Comment: I've got a nasty suspicion that the brown wire might once have been red.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Right, and the cuts aren't cuts, the insulation is brown because it got baked to death and it is now brittle and cracking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it, and deleted my previous answer. How ironic was finding the IC after saying "almost impossible to find" (facepalm).

Anyway, here it is: [AOZ1282](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ1282CI.pdf)

What we did wrong was to Google "BN0D" instead of **BN0**. A simple search for "smd marking BN0 sot-23-6" brought the result.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a RiCOH RP154?

I used this website for the SMD code:
https://smd.yooneed.one/code424e.html

This side has no direct match for BN0D, but for BN01 to BN09 and they are all the same part, only some variant.

The pin count does match to the photo. It being a volatage regulator makes sense.

Comment: I searched briefly too and ended up with various LDO as well. But this part is a switch regulator, not a LDO, or the coil and diode wouldn't be there. Unless U10 is the actual regulator maybe, but then the layout would be a bit strange.

Comment: thanks.  . what does the line below the "0" mean ?  it is number 0  or its a letter O ?

Comment: BNOD TC1301BNODVMF Microchip Technology
DFN-8      although the code is close to what I have . its a 8pin model not the 6 I have..

Answer (score -1):

can this be it :

[RP154N018B-TR-FE](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nisshinbo/RP154N018B-TR-FE?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvShe%252BZiYheihBjiN1j%2F9zxXMcHLmbvsMo%3D)

well, actually I see its up to 5v input.   and I have 24v . hmmmmmm

Comment: Isn't this the same (and incorrect) part already suggested by another answer?